# creating a object function prototype and code is wrong

Tags: javascript, prototype

Its part of a learning exercise and I want to create a prototype for functionsX with the string value of "name" and the code below is wrong..

```
function creatingFunctions(functionsX){

  functionsX.number=200;
 }

functionsX.prototype.propName=function(){
   return "name";
  };
```

Comment: Well, you're right that it's wrong. However, you have not explained what the intent of the code should be. Please take a look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: the intent is that every functionsX has the property propName thats value is a function which returns the string "name"-so I create a prototype

Comment: maybe declaring a variable in the first place would help...

Comment: functionsX.number = 200; is not the issue, it works just fine. My question is about the prototype

Comment: where should I declare a variable? how is that related to the prototype?

Comment: no that doesn't work (if I put it insight) and prototypes shouldn't outside as far as I understand

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all details required to answer the question, in the question.

Comment: The prototype is suppose to add the property with the value of a function which returns a string "name".

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a property in a function's prototype object should be in the same scope as where it is available.

```
function creatingFunctions(functionsX) { // Assuming functionsX is a function object.

  functionsX.number=200;
  functionsX.prototype.propName = function() {
   return "name";
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
function foo() {};
creatingFunctions(foo);
foo.propName(); // returns "name";
```

Instead of doing all that, you could have gone this way:

```
function Foo() {
    this.number = 200;
}

Foo.prototype.propName = function() {
    return "name";
}

// Usage would be:

var foo = new Foo();
foo.number // 200
foo.propName() // "name"
```

Comment: You probably meant `(new foo).propName();` in your first usage snippet